# Magento 2 How to call a ajax function in x-magento-init type javascript?

Tags: magento2, javascript

It seems cannot use jquery lib inside the x-magento-init type javascript.
How to call a ajax function in x-magento-init type javascript?
Thanks

Comment: How about your issue?

Comment: Please share more code when you call Ajax

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, we can call a ajax function in `x-magento-init`:

*vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml*

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {}
            }
        }
</script>
```

And then, navigate to 
*vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js*

```
ajaxSubmit: function(form) {
        ......
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                if (self.isLoaderEnabled()) {
                    $('body').trigger(self.options.processStart);
                }
            },
            success: function(res) {
               ......  
            }
        });
    },
```